# Is it possible to have a database trigger on restore in SQL 2005 or 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have some book keeping tasks (reset high water marks, clear some staged data) that need to be done after each restore of a QA database.  I know that I can create triggers on databases in SQL but I do not seem to be able to find a way to do it on a database restore.

Since I work on a team of people with shared ownership of the database, I cannot always know when a restore occurs.  Is there a way to automate this either with a trigger or some other database magic so that the cleanup procedure will always be called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no DDL trigger for RESTORE, there is however [Event Notification for the `AUDIT_BACKUP_RESTORE_EVENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190655.aspx) event, which will get you where you want.

Comment: There's a tiny problem with the event - it fires on backup/restore start. For some scenarios that's a desired behavior, however for others one have to employ sys.dm_exec_requests table in order to watch for restore session to complete.