# how do I get notified in .NET core when a database was restore in an instance

Tags: c#, database, .net-core

I want to log when a database gets restored(for example in sql server ) and I want to get notified in real time and in .net core . how can I have access to those events. I want to log them.

Comment: Hrmm I have never seen such thing, maybe there is something. The question really becomes what is the use case here why do you need to rely on this? Surely there is a better way

Comment: there is a way i know there is

Comment: Perhaps this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952611/is-it-possible-to-have-a-database-trigger-on-restore-in-sql-2005-or-2008

Comment: I am not judging, however why are you in this situation ?

Comment: Both event notifications and extended event sessions can capture this. You could then use a Service Broker queue to send a message to an outside application that's waiting on messages in that queue.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is there any library or class .net it self to be able to do this?

Comment: One again, but why. It seems there might be bigger problems

Comment: Not that I know of. There do exist classes that can read events from extended event sessions, though I can't find the docs of those at the moment. They are in any case not suitable for real-time event streaming but intended only to read events from files. You'd have to build the infrastructure for this yourself. If you are OK with "semi-real time" or just plain non-real time reporting, the problem is much easier as you can just poll the `restorehistory` logs in `msdb`.